# s3 cross account policy- Action does not apply to any resource error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have a cross account, which needs to access a bucket ( folder to be precise), when i apply this in terraform, i am getting an error , can someone please let me know, whats the error in this policy

I am trying to write s3 acl policy . The user should have only permission to folder1 inside  the bucket.

please point me how to use the condition ( i have the AccountA-CanonicalUserID) and username

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.xxx.id}"
     policy = <<POLICY
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "MicrositesLogs",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user1"
           },
          "Action": [
                      "s3:PutObject",
                      "s3:GetObject"
                    ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/folder1/*",
          "Condition": {
             "StringEquals": {
               "s3:x-amz-grant-full-control": "id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    POLICY
    }
```

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- aws_s3_bucket_policy.policy: 1 error(s) occurred:
- aws_s3_bucket_policy.policy: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement
      status code: 400, request id: 84C92DAD0C9AC0FB, host id: rvg7fqFDXdigCHPLLM/FXtOTXJXGKXSN9eQNRBZdkd0GrGRzis9ZkJu1Kkyu896RUvOx7mI7lcQ=

Comment: The problem here is that `s3:ListBucket` action will work only at the bucket level. All the resources that you have defined are at an object level. To fix this: either add the following resource as well: `arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxt-1` or add another statement just for  `s3:ListBucket` and in the resource section, add the bucket as the resource (best practice).

Comment: Earlier i had `GetObject and PutObject` it failed for that also, so does get object also works only at bucket level?

Comment: No, just `s3:ListBucket`.

Comment: i updated the question, got this error "Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3:x-amz-grant-full-control` is a condition key that requires the *creator* of an object to request that the listed permission be granted when objects are being created.  It doesn't grant anything -- it puts the burden on the uploader to make the grant, else the upload is denied.  It is thus impossible to match this condition on `s3:GetObject`, so if the system allowed you to create this policy, it would never work.